# How to capture Queueable class status when job is completed

Tags: apex, asyncapexjob, queueable-apex, queueable

I have created `Queueable` class to process data and making the `callouts` this `Queueable` class executes upon `after update` and `after insert` of `Opportunity` object.

Now in order to track the status of `Queueable` class I am inserting the status of job into another object i.e. `LogInfo` object. The purpose of this object is to keep track of jobs, status and error if any.

When the queueable gets executed i do insert the status of it using following code

Execute method of `Queueable` class

```
 public void execute(QueueableContext context) {


     SomeHandler.insertStatus(context.getJobId());

 }

 class SomeHandler {

    public Id insertStatus(Id jobId){


     AsyncApexJob apexJob = [SELECT Id ,Status,CompletedDate,ExtendedStatus, 
     NumberOfErrors,JobItemsProcessed,TotalJobItems,CreatedBy.Email 
                                FROM AsyncApexJob 
                                WHERE Id = :jobId];

     LogInfo__c logInfoObj = new LogInfo__c();
     // add job id 
     logInfoObj.JobId__c = jobId;
     // update status
     logInfoObj.JobStatus__c = apexJob.Status;



    }

 }
```

`SomeHandler.insertStatus` is being used by multiple `Queueable` classes , now the issue is so far I am able to record only `Processing` status as all calls to `insertStatus` are being made within the `exectue` method and what I really want to record is the `Completed` status. However, `Queueable` class does not have the `finish` method we do not have any space or hook where in we can record the `Queueable` class `Completed` status. In the end we waned to display the real-time dashboard of how many jobs are in the queue and how many are being processed , failed, and completed.

*Solutions did not work so far*

1. Can not create a trigger on `AsyncApexJob` object
2. Can not use `Transaction Finalizers` as it is a pilot and available for specially-configured scratch orgs

Comment: why not a near-real time dashboard using a scheduled job that runs every minute and that queries AsyncApexJob?

Comment: Yes , but I have to maintain the history of jobs as well because AsyncApexJob only store record of last 24 hours. Moreover, scheduled job minimum run Is of 1 hour and to set it run for every 1 min I have to run 60 jobs

Comment: The scheduled job can chain itself with a 1 minute displacement; you can also save the query results in a custom object

Comment: How is that and won't this approach create more jobs in Salesforce org

Comment: Use a chained queueable then.  SFDC will auto back off the chain to a one minute interval after the fourth item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a apex jobs view which is available out of the box with with new apex jobs interface.

If you want to do this manually there are two options:

1. Put you queue able code in `try/catch` and update the job status to complete at the end of the queuable as last line in `try` block or as a failure in the catch block . It may not work if the errors are non catch-able like limit exceptions.
2. Write a batch which runs every 15 minutes, queries the job status for records in log info and updates them.

Comment: Apex job Interface are you referring to?

Comment: In setup > Apex jobs

Comment: Even if the code is in finally it is still in execute method hence technically job is still running so option one won't help and for option two minimum schedule apex duration is of 1 hour so to schedule job after  every 15 mins , I have to schedule 4 jobs , which isn't a good solution

Comment: You could use Transaction finalizers but they are a pilot feature.

Comment: Yes hence I can't use it

Answer (score 2):

In spring 20 new feature is introduced by salesforce System.finalizer interface. You can use that interface that is an awesome feature. Refer to This Code for reference:

**Release Note:** https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_apex_Transaction_Finalizers.htm

**AccountUpdateLoggingFinalizer.Cls**

```
    public class AccountUpdateLoggingFinalizer implements Finalizer {
    // Used to maintain progress
    List<String> acctNames;

    public AccountUpdateLoggingFinalizer() {
        acctNames = new List<String>();
    }

    public void execute(FinalizerContext ctx) {        
        Id parentQueueableJobId = ctx.getAsyncApexJobId();
        System.Debug('Executing Finalizer that was attached to Queueable Job ID: ' + parentQueueableJobId);
        if (ctx.getAsyncApexJobResult() == FinalizerParentJobResult.SUCCESS) {
            // Queueable executed successfully
            System.Debug('Parent Queueable (Job ID: ' + parentQueueableJobId + '): completed successfully!');
        } else {
            // Queueable failed
            // Log some additional information.
            System.Debug('Parent Queueable (Job ID: ' + parentQueueableJobId + '): FAILED!');
            System.Debug('Parent Queueable Exception: ' + ctx.getAsyncApexJobException().getMessage());

            // Show the accounts that were processed before Queueable Job encountered the exception            
            System.Debug('Parent Queueable processed following accounts:');
            for (String acctName : acctNames) {
                System.Debug(acctName);
            }
        }        
    }

    public void reportProgress(Account acct) {
        acctNames.add(acct.Name);
    }
}
```

**AccountUpdateQueueable.cls --- Example to use interface**

```
public class AccountUpdateQueueable implements Queueable {

    public void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {

        // Create a transaction finalizer
        AccountUpdateLoggingFinalizer finalizer = new AccountUpdateLoggingFinalizer();

        // Attach the transaction finalizer to this queueable
        System.attachFinalizer(finalizer);

        // Do some (partial) work
        Account acct = new Account();
        acct.Name = '1st Account';
        insert(acct);

        // Send some status update to the finalizer
        finalizer.reportProgress(acct);

        // do some work that results in an unforeseen, uncatchable exception
        someWork();

        // Attempt to do some more work
        Account acct2 = new Account();
        acct2.Name = '2nd Account';
        insert(acct2);

        // Report more progress
        finalizer.reportProgress(acct2);
    }

    private void someWork() {
        // regular implementation that could result in an un-catchable
        // exception e.g. System.LimitException due to CPU usage over limits

        // for demonstration, try to enqueue 2 jobs so this method results in
        // System.LimitException because more than one job cannot be enqueued
        // from a Queueable
        System.enqueueJob(new FollowupActionQueueable());
        System.enqueueJob(new FollowupActionQueueable());
    }
}
```

Comment: This feature is not GA. It is available only in specially-configured scratch orgs.

Comment: As a note: TransactionFinalizers are currently beta in Spring '21 (51.0), and GA in Summer '21 (52.0). https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm